# Данные для приложения на Android

Tags: java, android

Пишу приложение, которое должно выдавать информацию о мероприятиях проходящих в том или ином городе. Я столкнулся с проблемой - где брать данные о мероприятиях для моего приложения? Я начал писать отдельную программу - парсер, с целью разместить ее на сервер и потом обращаться к ней из моего приложения. И вот внутри меня появилось сомнение - не изобретаю ли я велосипед и нельзя ли получить данные каким то иным путем, нежели городить свой веб сервис для приложения. Сформулирую вопрос понятнее: откуда мне брать данные для моего приложения? Продолжать писать свой веб сервис? Бросать изобретение велосипеда и использовать более рациональные подходы?

P.S. Приложение не коммерческое, пишу его для получения опыта разработки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

я бы рекомендовал для начала поискать открытые API. к примеру [kudago](https://kudago.com/pages/public-api/dlya-kogo-nashe-api/). для обучения вполне сойдет.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Не знал что у kudago открытый API. Парсил как раз этот сайт.